# how many biscuits can be made?

Tags: ratio

These are the following to make 20 biscuits: 
Flour:450g
Egg:350g
essence: 300g
milk:500g.

Question.
There are now 2kg of each components. What is the highest possible number of biscuits which can be made?

I have tried it like this:
If 1600g (by adding the mass of all components) = 20 biscuits then how much of 8000g make? Is this right?

Comment: The largest component is 500 g.of milk for the recipe of 20 biscuits.  That allows for at most $20 \times \frac{2000}{500} = $20\times 4= 80$.  We'll be out of milk then, though have surplus of other ingredients.

Comment: Suppose you need one kg of flour and just one gram of yeast  to make a loaf of bread, and you have $100$ kg of flour and $100$ kg of yeast. How many loaves can you make? Why can't you make $200$ loaves? If you think about this you will be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make 20 biscuits, the most ingredient you need is milk. So all you need to figure out is the amount of "packets" of milk you need, and obviously the other ingredients can also be made since less is required of them.

2kg = 2000 g, and divide that by 500 = 4 "packets" of biscuits.

So every packet can make 20 biscuits, so you can make at most 4*20 = 80 biscuits.